# Java while loop condition issue

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

This simple code is supposed to be try to make a game.Currently there is moveable green rectangle (player) and two black rectangles (enemies) with radiuses.If player enters raidus, enemy starts changing it's location.I want to achieve enemy rect. moving to x and y coords of player, but each time enemy hits x or y axis coords of player(only one of them, not both) it stops.I want it to finish also second axis movement.Why does it happen?I suppose problem could be in `run{}` method, considering that's place where is moving condition.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class Drawing extends JPanel implements KeyListener,Runnable
{
public static JFrame frame;
public static JLabel label;
public static int[] x=new int[10];
public static int[] y=new int[10];
public static int a;
public static Random random;
public static int p_x=0;
public static int p_y=0;
public static int enemy_stop=0;
public static boolean isin=false;
public static Thread move;
public static Rectangle active;
public static Rectangle[] generated=new Rectangle[10];;

public static void drawframe(int width,int height)
{       
    frame=new JFrame("The game");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(width,height);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    drawenemies(g,2);
    setradius(g);
    setplayer(g);

        if(entered()&&isin!=true)
        {
            isin=true;
            move=new Thread(new Drawing());
            move.start();
        }

        if(entered()==false&&isin!=false)
        {
            isin=false;
        }
}

public void drawenemies(Graphics g,int amount)
{
    random=new Random();
    a=amount;
    enemy_stop=enemy_stop+1;

    if(enemy_stop<=1)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=amount;i++)
        {
            x[i]=random.nextInt(frame.getWidth());
            y[i]=random.nextInt(frame.getHeight());
        }
    }   

    for(int i=1;i<=amount;i++)
    {   
        g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], 20, 20);
        Rectangle store=new Rectangle(x[i], y[i], 20, 20);
        generated[i]=store;
    }
}

public void setradius(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.RED);

    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        g.drawRect(x[i]-40, y[i]-40, 100, 100);
    }
}

public void setplayer(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(p_x, p_y, 20, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(p_x, p_y, 20, 20);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{   
    drawframe(500,500);
    Drawing instance=new Drawing();
    frame.add(instance);
    frame.addKeyListener(instance);

}

public boolean entered()
{
    boolean entered=false;

    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        Rectangle q=new Rectangle(x[i]-40, y[i]-40, 100, 100);
        Rectangle s=new Rectangle(p_x, p_y, 20, 20);

        if(q.contains(s))
        {
            entered=true;
            active=new Rectangle(x[i], y[i], 20, 20);
        }
    }

    return entered;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getKeyCode()==39)
    {
        p_x=p_x+10;
        repaint();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==37)
    {
        p_x=p_x-10;
        repaint();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==38)
    {
        p_y=p_y-10;
        repaint();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==40)
    {
        p_y=p_y+10;
        repaint();
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0){}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0){}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    try
    {

    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        if(active.getX()==generated[i].getX())
        {
            while(x[i]!=p_x&&y[i]!=p_y)
            {
                if(x[i]>p_x)
                    x[i]=x[i]-1;
                else
                    x[i]=x[i]+1;

                if(y[i]>p_y)
                    y[i]=y[i]-1;
                else
                    y[i]=y[i]+1;

                Thread.sleep(1500);
                frame.repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch(InterruptedException e)
{
}
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess in `while(x[i]!=p_x&&y[i]!=p_y)` should be `||` instead of `&&`

Also in `run`, `entered`, `setradius` and `drawenemies` methods for loop should be:
`for(int i=0; i < a; i++)`
because arrays in Java are numerated from `0` to `n-1` where `n` is the size of array. Your code will generate `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

In `keyPressed` method you could replace this four `if` with one switch statement.

You could also consider changing your mehtods names to [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)